# YouTube "Connection to server lost" on WiFi and 3G, stock 4.3

Tags: youtube, html5

I see the issue talked about online but none of the fixes work. I haven't been able to view for over a week. Does anyone have any other ideas? It also appears that some otherer html5 based videos aren't working but I can't think how to fix that.

Attempts:

- Phone off and on
- Clear YouTube cache
- Uninstall YouTube
- Check that my WiFi settings are suitable (no proxy)

Details:

- Stock Nexus 4, android 4.3
- Latest YouTube app
- No adblocker
- No root

Comment: Are you using Adblock Plus?

Comment: no, I haven't got adblock installed

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling YouTube, and re-installing it?

Comment: Are you using a Firewall?

Comment: Yes, reinstalled it and no, no firewall...

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution to the problem "Connection to server lost, touch to retry" on Wifi. In fact I used to encounter this problem on my Samsung Galaxy S2  device. The solution is as follows:

1. First make sure you have a Google account which you use to download applications from Google Play Store.
2. Open the YouTube application on your device.
3. At the top left hand corner of your screen, you would find the YouTube icon with 3 short lines to its left.
4. click on it (touch it) and there is a pop up menu which appears
5. If you have not yet signed into YouTube with the gmail account, the

Comment: You seem to be missing the end of your post.

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall all of the updates to YouTube and it will fix the issue.